# How to use OR condition in while loop in bash

Tags: bash

Im trying to create a simple bash script which does a check of command up three times.

The OR condition `$I -lt 3  -o -z "$EXEC"` is not stopping the loop when one of the coditions is reach and i dont know why... How should i do the or condition correcly?

```
!/bin/bash

while  [ $I -lt 3  -o -z "$EXEC" ]
do
  I=$((I+1))
  echo "[$I] executing the command again..."
  EXEC=comand...
  sleep 1
done
```

**EDIT**
My solution "for while" (until this work) was check the *$I* value in a *if statement* and *break* the *while loop*, like:

```
if [ "$I" -eq "3" ]; then
    break
fi
```

Comment: Without knowing how it's "not working correctly", it's really hard to guess. But there are some parsing ambiguities with `-o`, so `[ $I -lt 3  ] || [ -z "$EXEC" ]` is generally better.

Comment: What is `$I` when you first compare against `3`?? (set `I=0` before the loop) ***Always quote your variables within*** `[..]`, e.g. `[ "$I" -lt '3' -o -z "$EXEC" ]` -- *even if you think it will only contain an integer*. Quote the `'3'` to prevent filename expansion (yes people have files named `3`)

Comment: `3` is not affected by filename expansion, even if you have a file named `3`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin following your instructions the while is not stopping when $I > 3... Why it is not working?

Comment: @GordonDavisson the question was updated, "not working" was meaning that the while loop is not stopping when one of the conditions in reach

Comment: `one of the conditions`? It's OR. The loop will run until "$I" is lower then 3 __or__ "$EXEC" is an empty string. If `EXEC=command` always makes `"$EXEC"` an empty string, the loop will run forever. What is the value of `"$EXEC"` when `"$I"` reaches 3?

Comment: @KamilCuk sometimes it is empty, sometimes is completed while the string

Comment: It's __OR__. Not __AND__. I can guess that your intent was to use `-a` flag...

Comment: @KamilCuk it worked! But im bit confused, because the man says that -a if **AND** and -o is **OR**

Comment: Yes.. ? `while  [ $I -lt 3  -o -z "$EXEC" ]` - execute the loop until "$l" is lower then 3 or EXEC is empty. until $i ... or until exec ... . So If any of the conditions are true (the meaning of OR) then execute the loop. So $l must be lower then 3 or EXEC must be empty. ...

Comment: @KamilCuk OMG! My bad! You are right! :d If you want, convert your comment to an answer and i will accept it.